# CLLocationManager didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation: sometimes not called

Tags: ios-simulator, cllocationmanager, xcode5

For some reason didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation: doesn't always get called in CLLocationManagerDelegate.
What's weird, on the first run everything is always okay.

Checked for [CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] - it always equals kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorized.

Code that starts updating location:

```
locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
locationManager.delegate = self;
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

P.S. I'm using XCode 5 DP simulator.

Answer (score 0):

The extended discussion of the methods that initialize the delegate method reveal some circumstances where the delegate is not called when one might expect. I've pulled this from the docs... Please advise if this sufficiently answers the question.

This method returns immediately. Calling this method causes the location manager to obtain an initial location fix (which may take several seconds) and notify your delegate by calling its locationManager:didUpdateLocations: method. (In iOS 5 and earlier, the location manager calls the locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation: method instead.) After that, the receiver generates update events primarily when the value in the distanceFilter property is exceeded. Updates may be delivered in other situations though. For example, the receiver may send another notification if the hardware gathers a more accurate location reading.

Calling this method several times in succession does not automatically result in new events being generated. Calling stopUpdatingLocation in between, however, does cause a new initial event to be sent the next time you call this method.

If you start this service and your application is suspended, the system stops the delivery of events until your application starts running again (either in the foreground or background). If your application is terminated, the delivery of new location events stops altogether. Therefore, if your application needs to receive location events while in the background, it must include the UIBackgroundModes key (with the location value) in its Info.plist file.